# ini-config for Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache, zend-config

How to configure Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page in application.ini? I cannot define regexps (see example http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html#zend.cache.frontends.page.examples. It should be something like following

```
resources.cachemanager.page.frontend.options.regexps.^/$.cache = true
```

But it is a bad ini-file syntax, it fails with

> Zend_Config_Exception: syntax error, unexpected '$'

Comment: You could try `resources.cachemanager.page.frontend.options.regexps['^/$'].cache = true`. But I doubt it will work, based on Marcin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do it. According to [parse_ini_file](http://au.php.net/parse_ini_file) manual: `Characters ?{}|&~![()^" must not be used anywhere in the key and have a special meaning in the value`. Notice that **^** is in the set of these characters.

However, what is interesting, when you remove **$** from your key, and leave only **^/** you should not get any error. So it seems that the problem is only with **$**. But I don't know how to use it as a key in a ini file.

In this situation I would recommend setting regexps in your Bootsrap.php. You could define custom variables in application.ini, regexps should be allowed in values, and add them to cachemanager resource in your Bootsrap.php.